# What is the safest, simplest, most versatile proguard config?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

My proguard config is hell, crashing my game and seems to not properly. What is the simplest, safest config to use for one-fits-all until I figure out what the hell is wrong? Is there maybe any way to make it change only variable names? Or just obfuscate the code to make it harder to read without breaking anything so much

Answer (score 0):

You should check ProGuard outputs (ex. usage.txt) and [customize which code to keep manually](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html#keep-resources).

Answer (score 0):

There is no simple or safe, general config if you use external libraries/frameworks. If your app uses just some simple Android APIs then you could just use the default config that Android comes with.